# mySQL adding a conditional inside case clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Essentially I have the following stored procedure that give the right response, but I would like to add additional logic that states if the response for TimeDiff is negative, respond with a 0, otherwise respond with difference (TimeLeft).

```
BEGIN

SELECT
`Person`,`Code`,
CASE 
WHEN `Problem` = "Large" 
THEN 500 - (TIME_TO_SEC((TimeDiff(Now(),`Start`)/60))) END AS TimeLeft

FROM Table1
WHERE `Code` = "1111"; 

END
```

Comment: See GREATEST().

Answer (score 1):

You can nest `CASE` inside `CASE`:

```
SELECT
    `Person`,
    `Code`,
    CASE WHEN 
        `Problem` = "Large" 
    THEN 
        CASE WHEN
            500 - (TIME_TO_SEC((TimeDiff(Now(),`Start`)/60))) < 0
        THEN
            0
        ELSE
            500 - (TIME_TO_SEC((TimeDiff(Now(),`Start`)/60))) 
        END
    END AS TimeLeft
FROM Table1
WHERE `Code` = "1111";
```

Or, you can use the function [`GREATEST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest) that is specific to MySQL:

```
SELECT
    `Person`,
    `Code`,
    CASE WHEN 
        `Problem` = "Large" 
    THEN
        GREATEST(500 - (TIME_TO_SEC((TimeDiff(Now(),`Start`)/60))), 0)
    END AS TimeLeft
FROM Table1
WHERE `Code` = "1111";
```

Comment: @Strawberry, I'm not very familiar with functions specific to MySQL. Your suggestion to use `GREATEST` is very nice.

Comment: Actually, almost every database supports `GREATEST()` and `LEAST()`.  I don't recall but they might be standard functions, because they all hand `NULL` in an arcane way -- suggesting that weird standards are involved.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, `GREATEST` is **not** in a standard and it works differently in, say, MySQL and Postgres with NULLs. These two facts could be enough for somebody to avoid using these functions. SQL Server doesn't have it at all.